# Check if h2 database is corrupted and create new if corrupted

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I'm a C# developer and need to maintain an existing Java Service application developed using spring boot framework. The responsible developer left the company some time ago so I have no possibility to get some help... 
So far I have no experience with Java and the used spring boot framework.

What I need to achive:

- Check if used h2 Database is corrupted
- If corrupted: Delete the database and create a new empty one

I guess I need to implement the check and recreation in the main entry point

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessageServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
```

As I know spring-boot and Hibernate creates the db automatically on startup if the database does not exists. So far so good. Now I need to check if the database is corrupted. I thought about executing a query on the database and if I get an exception I recreate the database.

The Database is a h2 file database.

Hopefully I can get some assistance.

**Edit #1**
I thought about implementing a utils class which gets called on startup:

```
public class H2DbUtils {

public boolean IsH2FileDatabaseCorrupted()
{
    boolean isCorrupted = false;

    // Implement Logic to determine if db is corrupted

    return isCorrupted;
}

public boolean ReCreateH2DatabaseFile()
{
    boolean reCreated = false;
    // Implement Logic to recreate db

    return reCreated;
}
```

}

Calling this class on startup

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        H2DbUtils h2DbUtils = new H2DbUtils();
        if(h2DbUtils.IsH2FileDatabaseCorrupted()) {
            h2DbUtils.ReCreateH2DatabaseFile();
        }

        SpringApplication.run(MessageServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
```

**Update 2018-03-20**

Currently found the following solution to achive this:

```
@Configuration
@Component

public class DataSourceBean {

    @Autowired
    private Environment currentEnvironment;
    private final Logger logInstance = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DataSource dataSource = null;

        try
        {
            // We try to get the Meta Data out of the database.
            // If this fails the database is corrupted or has an other problem
            // All in all this means we need to delete the current database file
            // to avoid further problems.
            dataSource = this.getDataSource();
            dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData();
            return dataSource;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logInstance.error("The h2 database file '{}' seems to be corrupted! Error: {}",
                                currentEnvironment.getProperty("dataBaseFile"),
                                ex.getMessage());

        // dataBaseFile=./db/mydatabase.db           
            String databaseFilePath = String.format("%s.%s", currentEnvironment.getProperty("dataBaseFile"), "h2.db");
            databaseFilePath = databaseFilePath.replace("/", "\\");

            File databaseFile = new File(databaseFilePath);

            if (databaseFile.exists()) {


                File parentDirectory = new File(databaseFile.getParent());
                if (parentDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                    try {

                        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(parentDirectory);
                    } catch (Exception fex) {

                        logInstance.error("Error occurred deleting the folder {}. Error: {}",
                                            parentDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                                            fex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            dataSource = this.getDataSource();
        }
        finally {

            return dataSource;
        }
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    private DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(currentEnvironment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
                .driverClassName(currentEnvironment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"))
                .username(currentEnvironment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
                .password(currentEnvironment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: The database is created automatically *if so configured*. I have no idea why you would write logic to check for a corrupted database, is it supposed to be a common occurrence that your db gets corrupted? Is it just a minor inconvenience, because you can just create a new db?

Comment: Yes. The database gets corrupted very often in the past. Thats why I have the job to implement a logic to check whether the db is corrupted or not and if so recreate the database file. The data gets automatically into the database. This was already implemented before. **Edit**: yes - if the db does not exist its created automatically by configuration.

Comment: So you have software that was written badly from the start, and now you, a C# developer will have to maintain it. I wish you luck, you're going to need it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also not very happy with this situation but yea. Thanks for wishing me luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to overwrite the DataSource bean and check database files

```
@Bean
@Primary // this will override the datasource autoconfiguration and use your own everywhere
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // Open Connection
    // Check Database
    // Close Connection
    // IF File corrupted delete files
    // create regular data source
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That approach brought me on the "right" track I was searching for. Based on your comment I've updated the init Post. Question: I Assume that the implementation is executed everytime the application asks for the dataSource - correct?

Comment: No, DataSource is a Singleton Bean and is created only once.

Comment: Great thanks. As I've just fixed the symptoms I need to get the root cause for the problem. Is there a way to catch datasource related exceptions at a global place? So that I have the posibility to check when the database gets corrupted based on the executed db operations.

Comment: To catch all exceptions on the executed db operations you have no centeralized place. The only possibility i think is to wrap all SQL classes/instances like datasource, connection, statement, preparedstatement, resultset, .... with a proxy but this will be a lot of hard work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to add several listeners to the spring boot application, for example:

```
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(testApplication.class);
    springApplication.addListeners(new FailedEvent(testApplication.class));
    SpringApplication.run(testApplication.class, args);
```

But I never get to one of this listeners in the startup of the spring application. As SpringApplication.run seems to initzialise the whole spring context it is also not possible to inject or get the configuration environment to get the connection string as the application stops within SpringApplication.run as the db is corrupted.

I assume that spring tries to initzialise hibernate and so on and fails to create a database connection as the db is corrupted

```
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=2 SYS"
General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=2 SYS" [50000-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:307) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:270) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:64) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:176) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
```

This happens within the SpringApplicatio.run context. Before I found no chance to check if the db is corrupted and if so delete the database.